# Removing all "br" and "p" tags from a text/string in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a text/string of:

```
<br /><p>Serkan Ercan'ın yolu bu sefer de bozulmamış Akdeniz ve
okyanus sahilleri, verimli toprakları ve hemen yanı başında bulunan
çölüyle Kuzey Afrika'nın en şanslı ülkesi olan Fas'a düşüyor.</p>
<p>Geçmişte nice imparatorluklara ev sahipliği yapmış bu masal ülkesi
zengin bir tarihin mirasçısı. Her şehri farklı bir atmosfere sahip bu
güzel ülkede Serkan Ercan'ın ilk rotası filmlere adını vermiş meşhur
şehir Kazablanka.</p> <p>Adı İspanyolca'da “Beyaz Ev” anlamına gelen
Kazablanka, denizi, tarihi dokusu, mimarisi ve doğal güzellikleriyle
kusursuz güzellikleri bir arada sunan masalsı bir şehir. Üç milyonluk
nüfusuyla Magrep ülkeleri içinde en büyük konuma sahip bu şehir, aynı
zamanda Fas'ın en önemli ticaret merkezi ve en büyük liman kenti. <br
/> <br /> Eski Şehir ile Yeni Şehir ve bu iki merkezin etrafına
yayılmış çeşitli turistik mekanlarıyla birçok görülecek yere sahip
Kazablanka, hem egzotik hem de modern mimariden izler taşıyor.</p>
<p>Şehrin en önemli sembollerinden biri İkinci Hasan Camii. Bu
görkemli yapı Fas eski kralı II. Hasan’ın 1989’da 60. doğum gününe
yetiştirilmek için yoğun çabalar sarf edilerek inşa edilse de binlerce
işçinin sabah akşam çalışmasına rağmen ancak 1993’te tamamlanabilmiş.
Önündeki devasa meydan ile beraber 105 bin kişinin aynı anda namaz
kılabileceği şekilde tasarlanan caminin minaresi 210 metrelik
yüksekliğiyle yeryüzündeki en yüksek minare ünvanına sahip. Atlantik
Okyanusu'nun üzerine inşa edilen bu mermer yapı gerçekten de
büyüleyici.</p> <p>1710'da, Moulay Ismail tarafından yapılan Kasbah
Boulaouane Kalesi Casablanca'nın sahip olduğu en güzel manzarayı
izlemek için ideal bir mekan. Kentin gürültüsünden uzaklaşmak isteyen
halkın tercih ettiği yerlerden biri olan kaleyi görmeden bu güzel
şehirden ayrılmak olmaz.</p> <p>Kazablanka'daki eğlenceli gezisini
bitiren Serkan Ercan'ın ikinci durağı geçmişte Fas Sultanlığı'na
başkentlik yapmış olan Fes şehri. Fas'ın geleneksel yapısının daha
yalın bir şekilde gözlemlenebildiği bu şehir, dünyada Orta Çağ
yerleşimi bütün olarak korunmuş en iyi şehirlerden biri.</p>
<p>Labirent gibi daracık neredeyse on bin sokak ve bu sokaklarda yer
alan küçücük dükkanlardan oluşan bu tarihi şehirde kaybolmamak mümkün
değil. Fez’de görülecek en önemli yer kuşkusuz eski şehir yani Fez
Medina'sı. Fez Medinası Fas’ın en önemli yerel alışveriş
merkezlerinden biri, toplam 13 bin dükkan olduğu söylenen bu büyük
pazarda, deri ürünleri, porselenler, baharatlar ve daha birçok ürünü
bulabilirsiniz. Fes'teki tarihi yapıları ziyaret eden Serkan Ercan
şekerle tuzun karıştığı lezzetli Fas mutfağını da keşfe çıkıyor.</p>
<p>Fas'ın gizemli sokaklarında keşfe çıkan ünlü oyuncu yerel halkla
yaptığı keyifli sohbetlerle dolu bir bölümle İZ ekranlarında...</p>
```

How can I remove all of br and p tags from this text with regex in php? It's very complicated to me, so I had to ask.
My code in short:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');


$sContent = file_get_contents('http://iztv.com.tr/program.aspx?id='.$_GET['id']);

$DOM = str_get_html($sContent);

$description = $DOM -> find('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_aciklama',0)->innertext;

//print_r($m);

$arr['aciklama'] = addslashes($description);

$json->result->program_detayi[] = $arr;
echo json_encode($json, true);

?>
```

Comment: why not just use `->plaintext`

Comment: plaintext worked just as I wanted, thanks @Ghost

Comment: yeah no unnecessary regex, string replace or any of those kind, just use that and you're done

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regexp to do this, you can do it with a simple find and replace:

```
$string = str_replace(['<br>','<br />','<p>','</p>'], '', $string);
```

Comment: This won't handle cases when `<br />` looks like `<br>` or `<br/>`. Maybe it is not the case here, just FYI.

Comment: @stribizhev It will handle `<br>`, thats the first thing in my array. I didn't include `<br/>` because valid XHTML needs the space.

Comment: :) I am sorry to overlook the `<br>`. I just know some good amount of cases when we had to deal with `<br/>`, and it is something we get from a veeery expensive commercial tool. I'd add that, too. And make the tag check case-insensitive.